# catching thrown errors from callback function javascript

Tags: node.js, error-handling, callback, fs

I'm running some functions inside try-catch. I'm using fs.unlink to remove some files on request. but if there is not such a file I want to throw an error. but I can't catch the error. it always causes the app to crash

this is my code:

```
  app.delete("/product", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.body.id;

    try {
      Product.findByPk(id)
        .then((product) => {
          if(product) {
            const images = JSON.parse(product.image);

            for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
              fs.unlink(`public/images/${images[i]}`, (err) => {
                if (err) throw new Error(err);
              });
            }
    
            product.destroy();
          }else {
            res.status(404).json({ msg: "can't delete product with id: " + id + ". It doesn't exist in database."});
          }
        });
      res.status(200).json({ msg: "Deleted product with id: " + id });
    } catch (error) {      
      res.status(500).json({ msg: "An error with code 'NW_DELETE_1' occured." });
      Log.error("ERROR is this: " + error);
    }

  });
```

the Product.finByPk is from `Sequelize`

and Log object is from `bunyan` logger.

can you please show me how can I handle every possible error in this block of code?
I wan't to catch the error and log it to console using Log. I wan't to avoid programmer errors like non-existing file for deleting on fs.unlink.

I'm new to programming. please note any mistake you find.

Comment: Rather then using throw error use- console.log(err). throw error crashes your app

Comment: I know how to log error. but I want to catch it. I want to prevent app from crashing

Comment: You are catching it with `if (err) throw new Error(err);`, but you throw the error again in the same line. If you don't want to it crash and log it, you can replace that line with: `if (err) Log.error("ERROR is this: " + error);`

Comment: I think you are right. I don't need to throw any error here. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, try-catch cannot catch the exception because your code is executed asynchronously in the `.then()` handler.

You need to add a `.catch()` handler:

```js
  app.delete("/product", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.body.id;

    Product.findByPk(id)
      .then((product) => {
        if (product) {
          const images = JSON.parse(product.image);

          for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            fs.unlink(`public/images/${images[i]}`, (err) => {
              if (err) throw new Error(err);
            });
          }
  
          product.destroy();
          res.status(200).json({ msg: "Deleted product with id: " + id });
        } else {
          res.status(404).json({ msg: "can't delete product with id: " + id + ". It doesn't exist in database."});
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).json({ msg: "An error with code 'NW_DELETE_1' occured." });
        Log.error("ERROR is this: " + error);   
      });
  });
```